# Problems with qsort() with struct containing char*

Tags: c, qsort

`table.h`:

```
#ifndef table_h
#define table_h   

//  The object:
typedef struct Pair
{
    char* name;
    int number;
} Pair;

int comp_pair(const void* lhs, const void* rhs)
{
    Pair* lp = (Pair*) lhs;
    Pair* rp = (Pair*) rhs;

    const char* ln = lp->name;
    const char* rn = rp->name;

    return strcmp(ln, rn);
}

// The array and associated functions:
size_t table_capacity;                                           
size_t table_size;                                               
Pair* table;            // <------ Global variables -------------------

Pair* create_table (size_t capacity)
{
    Pair* p = 0;
    p = (Pair*) malloc(sizeof(*p) * capacity);

    if (p == NULL && capacity > 0)
    {
        perror("create_table()::bad allocation!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    table_capacity = capacity;

    return p;
}    

void insert (Pair* table, const char* name, int number)
{
    Pair* p = (Pair*) malloc(sizeof(*p));

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        perror("insert::bad allocation!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    p->name = name;
    p->number = number;

    table[table_size++] = *p;
}

void print_table(Pair p[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s -> %d\n", p[i].name, p[i].number);
    }
}

#endif
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     // qsort() 
#include <string.h>     // strcmp()
#include <stddef.h>     // size_t
#include "table.h"

int main()
{
    char* names [ ] = { "bla1", "bla2", "bla3", "bla4", "bla5"};
    int numbers [ ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    size_t s = 5;
    size_t i = 0;

    table = create_table(s);

    for (i; i < s; ++i)
    {
        insert(table, names[i], numbers[i]);    
    }

    qsort(table, table_size, sizeof(Pair), comp_pair);

    print_table(table, table_size);
    getchar();

    free(table);
}
```

When I try to use `qsort()`, (debugging) the above code generates the following error:

> `Access violation reading location 0x65727541.`

Questions:

1. Is the function comp_pair() correct?
2. What size should I pass as a third parameter in qsort(), the current sizeof(Pair) or the size of the actually compared types, i.e. char*?

Comment: cannot reproduce with the code shown. Although there ARE problems (like `const` correctness, a memory leak in `insert()` and a questionable design with a global for the size of something that's returned as an instance) -- the code should work as intended. Is there some code missing?

Comment: Not to real problem, but you have meory leak in `insert`. You allocate Pair, initialize it, copy contents to table, and then forget to free it. You don't need malloc for that, you can use next table index to initialize the pointer.

Comment: Besides a memory leak in your insert() function, the code you posted here looks fine, as long as you have the proper `#include`s The issue is with something else, make sure your actual code matches the code you posted here.

Comment: Thank you all for the remarks! This is all the code that I use, the only missing line is a `getchar()` at the end. I'll remove the allocation in `insert()` as suggested.

Comment: @nos code is absolutelly not ok. Not just leak in insert, but also no need for any malloc. And I got downvotes for correct answer.

Comment: The code in the question is not related to the error you get. I know this because the pointer you fault on is most likely a string that contains the characters "Atre"

Comment: `p->name = name;` is not good plus the twice memory allocation. allocate name instead

Comment: *"This is all the code that I use"* As @nos said, if those snippets are on different files, then lack of `#include` could be a problem. Please create [mcve] and clarify your post.

Comment: And enable compiler warnings. If it's just a missing `#include`, a decent compiler should emit a clear warning.

Comment: You misuse a `.h` file to contain code and variables (instead of just their declarations), but this still doesn't explain the problem....

Comment: `create_table` should use `calloc`. You really want each cell to be zeroed (at least to ease debuggging), not left uninitialized.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I will change to `calloc()`, thank you.

Comment: [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Despite all minor errors, this code as shown here *should not crash*. Which compiler (+version) are you using and on which platform? Which standard C library (+version) is linked? Which flags do you use during compilation? If this **really** is all your code, there's maybe something wrong with the compiler or runtime.

Comment: @FelixPalmen MVC++Express2010, Windows 10. Everything (flags) is to its default settings.

Comment: [it works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89f60c4ff325167e)

Comment: @Ziezi Then you are running e.g. an old executable that's not the result of compiling this code. If you create a new solution/project, copy paste the code from here into 2 new files, main.c and table.h, build and run that code, you don't get the crash you have reported.

Comment: No matter what, start by getting rid of the spaghetti globals.

Comment: @nos pff, I'll follow your advice, thank you!

Comment: @Lundin I understand, the thing is that I'm given (interface) function prototypes, that does not have parameters for the `size`, `capacity`, etc...I don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: @Ziezi The table and its size you allocate and keep track of in main(). The `table_capacity` variable aren't used so it can be removed. And that's it.

Comment: @Lundin I see, thank you!